# Include functions from package in development into examples for functions of the same package

Tags: r, r-package

When developing an R package, how can I rely on functions that are part of that package in examples for other functions of that package?

Suppose I have a function generating sample data inside my package named `testdata()`

In another function named `modify_data()` I want to modify sample data generated with `testdata()`

How can I refer to the function `testdata()` in the `@example` of the roxygen2 skeleton?
I tried the following:

```
#' @examples
#' sample_data <- testdata(some_parameters)
#' sample_data <- modify_data(sample_data)
```

or

```
#' @examples
#' sample_data <- mypackagename::testdata(some_parameters)
#' sample_data <- modify_data(sample_data)
```

But when R CMD checking the package contents I always get an error for the examples saying:

```
Error: could not find function "testdata"
```

or

```
Error: 'testdata' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mypackagename'
```

Is it possible to rely on other package functions inside the examples for another function? I feel like it should work somehow, but cannot get behind the correct way to do so...

Comment: You can only use exported functions in examples. It looks like you should export `testdata`.

Comment: @Roland, post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

The examples on a help page should allow the user to copy/paste the code and have it run successfully to demonstrate the correct use of a package (or run when calling `example(modify_data)`). That means that all the functions used in the example need to be exported from the package you are creating. It appears you are using roxygen so you can mark the function you want to use as exported with

```
@export
testdata <- function(...) {
  ...
}
```

Though it might not make sense to have a function called `testdata` exported from your package if that's not really part of your API. You can [include sample datasets in your package](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) or define data in the example itself like they do in the `?lm` help page.